# How to intercept broadcast mediaplayer event in Android?

Tags: android

I need to play and stop my application through headset buttons... I found something about com.android.music.musicservicecommand , if I send a broadcast Intent doing

```
    Intent intentStop;
    intentStop = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
    intentStop.putExtra("command", "stop");
    SomafmApp.mycontext.sendBroadcast(intentStop);
```

media player stops. Do you have a sample code to intercept these events in my application? I found very little around internet, I start thinking that this method is deprecated, but maybe I'm wrong...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html . It works great, and shows how to mantain a backward compatibility. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find what you're looking for here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=415.  It provides sample code for controlling the MediaPlayer with headphone controls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but found something better this morning...have a look to my answer ^^